# why does vue-lazyload listen 'wheel' , 'touchmove' and 'scroll' events at the same time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lazy-loading

vue-lazyload's default events to listen includes 'scroll', 'wheel', 'mousewheel', 'resize','animationend', 'transitionend' and 'touchmove'.

```
var DEFAULT_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'wheel', 'mousewheel', 'resize', 'animationend', 'transitionend', 'touchmove'];
```

When 'wheel' or 'touchmove' emits, 'scroll' emits, too.
Is it  necessary to listen 'wheel'  and 'touchmove' when it has listened 'scroll' event?